# Why is the Gibbs free energy of titanium(IV) chloride reduction to titanium metal positive?

Tags: physical-chemistry, thermodynamics, free-energy

I use the Ellingham diagram to find the Gibbs free energy at the equilibrium state to find the partial pressure of chlorine. I have to use the Van 't Hoff reaction isotherm and the partial pressure of chlorine to determine whether it is thermodynamically feasible to reduce the titanium contained in titanium tetrachloride to form titanium metal at $\pu{800 °C}$ in an atmosphere with a chlorine partial pressure of $\pu{1E-20 atm}$ (assume an otherwise inert atmosphere).

I solved

$$\Delta_\mathrm{r}G = -RT\ln K + RT\ln Q$$

by finding $K$ at equilibrium condition and $Q$ (using new partial pressure). If $\Delta_\mathrm{r}G < 1,$ the reaction is feasible.

My answer is positive, which means the reaction is not feasible. Why the free energy is positive here? It should be negative as the reaction can occur below this partial pressure, right?

Comment: Convenient reference for text/formula formatting:
 [Notation basics](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help/notation)  /  [Formatting of math/chem expressions](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86/how-can-i-format-math-chemistry-expressions-here)  /  
[upright vs italic](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/443/which-symbols-are-written-in-roman-upright-font-and-which-are-italicized)  // [For more:  Math SE MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).  // Keep CH SE Q titles in plain text.

Comment: Might be helpful to show your calculations

Comment: How can I add picture here?

Comment: It should be $\Delta_r G \lt 0$ , not $\Delta_r G \lt 1$.

Comment: @Learnphy consider following up on all these helpful comments if you are interested in an answer here, otherwise your question may get closed.